# Datalist_ItemCommand event not firing

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have a datalist that has an item_Command event that is never firing.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if (!IsPostBack)
              DataList1.DataSource = mySource;
    }

    protected void DataList1_ItemCommand(object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
         //dostuff
    }



    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="DataList1_ItemCommand"
                            OnItemCreated="DataList1_ItemCreate">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Button ID="ButtonEditTask" runat="server" Width="60px" Text="Edit" CommandName="edit" />
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </ItemTemplate> 
                        </asp:DataList>
```

When I do the postback, my datasource is null since I am not re assigning, therefore my event handler doesnt fire. So in order to fix it being null, i tried overriding init

```
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        DataList1.DataSource = mySessionSource;
    }
```

Now I know the reason why its not working is because either 
1. My Datasource is null BEFORE I added in the Override method and
2. My Controls event handler isn't being created in time since its rebinding every postback.

To fix 1, I added a datasource.
To fix 2 I added a datasource in init.

This didn't seem to fix anything however, and I do not know why. I also tried adding an event_handler in my init and it didn't do anything.

Comment: You shouldn't need the override.  Does your Page_Init bind the datasource?  If not, it'll always be empty and the OnCreated event will never fire.

Comment: My Page_Load binds the datasource as in the post above. It binds it there and on the override. Unless if the Page_Init is a different built in method call?

Comment: Assigning and binding are two separate steps.  See my answer for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're binding the datasource to `DataList1` otherwise the DataList will always be empty and the `OnItemCreated` event will never fire.  You shouldn't need the `OnInit` override.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
         DataList1.DataSource = mySource;
         DataList1.DataBind();
     }
}
```